# Get last name first in biblatex using numeric style

Tags: biblatex

Below is a short example of my code.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,
style=numeric,
sorting=nyt,
bibencoding=utf8,
defernumbers=true,
 natbib=true,
 ]{biblatex}

 \DefineBibliographyStrings{danish}{andothers = {et\addabbrvspace al\adddot}}

\addbibresource{Reference}

\begin{document}
This is a reference see \citep{Ovesen2012} and \citep{ctan}
\printbibliography[title={Referencer}]
\end{document}
```

In the file "Reference" there are the following:

```
@article{ctan,
author  = "George D. Greenwade",
title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
year    = "1993",
journal = "TUGBoat",
volume  = "14",
number  = "3",
pages   = "342--351",
keywords  = "latex"
}


@Book{Ovesen2012,
author = {Jens Ovesen and Marianen Hall and Ulirik Oven},
title = {An introduktion to latex},
publisher = {Polyteknisk forlag},
year = {2013},
}
```

I get the result as shown below, but I want the last names first, so it looks like this:

Greenwade, George D. "The Comprehensive Tex Archive Network (CTAN)".
In: TUGBoat 14.3 (1993), pp. 342-351.

Ovesen, Jens; Marianen Hall and Ulirik Oven. An introduktion to latex.
Polyteknisk forlag, 2013.

[image]

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}` to your preamble.

Comment: For consistency reasons you might also want to add `\DeclareNameAlias{editor}{last-first}` and `\DeclareNameAlias{translator}{last-first}`. Alternatively, `\DeclareNameAlias{default}{last-first}` is shorter, but changes the format of some other names as well.

Comment: @moewe yes, you're right. But since the op only asked about the author, I decided to leave those out.

Comment: Fair enough, in my experience though, people often just use "author" as an umbrella term when, as far as `biblatex` is concerned, they could also mean editor and trasnslator. Just cite `sigfridsson` and `matuz:doody` in an example file with only `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}` and have a look at the terribly inconsistent output.

Comment: I'm using `\usepackage[round,authoryear]{natbib}` and I can't add the `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}` line, it gives me the following error `! Undefined control sequence. l.189 \DeclareNameAlias `

Comment: @mcExchange Because you use the `natbib` package and the command mentioned above is for the `biblatex` package.