# How to display surname first in bibliography?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, bibliographystyle

I want my bibliography to be shown in the format of the next example:

[image]

The journal's instructions:

> **Form of author name:** For all authors, use initials, without periods or spaces between them, in lieu of expanded given and middle names. Include the authors’ surnames in full. The listing for each author should be in inverted-order surname-first format. Commas should separate individual author names. The word “and” should not precede the final author name for reference entries with ten or fewer authors. If more than ten individuals authored a resource, the reference entry documenting the resource should list the first ten authors followed by “et al.” Do not use em-dashes to replace author names if names repeat.

I am using:

- `\documentclass[]{interact}`
- `\usepackage[superscript,biblabel]{cite}`
- `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}`
- and Bibtex file

How to do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Does this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290103/get-last-name-first-in-biblatex-using-numeric-style

Comment: I tried `\bibliographystyle{acm}` but it does not give an incrementing digit when citing a reference within the text, also the surname and first-name must not be separated by comma (as shown in the image above)

Comment: I see. Perhaps you want to show a short compilable example so that people here know how to help.

Comment: @modnar yes, thank you. In fact, I didn't find any predefined bibliography style to do that.

Comment: The wording of your requirements seems to be the one from Taylor & Francis' NLM style (https://tandf.co.uk//journals/authors/style/reference/tf_USVancouver.pdf). There is an Overleaf template for that style that appears to be official: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/taylor-and-francis-latex-template-for-authors-interact-layout-plus-nlm-reference-style/bngwgqnxcxrp. Maybe that helps. (Note that the output produced by the template might not be the same as a published article, but it might be good enough.) ...

Comment: ... It's probably best to contact the editor and ask them about LaTeX submissions and which style to use, before you go down the rabbit hole of trying to find a matching `.bst` file.

Comment: @moewe, thank you. They already sent me their template, but it doesn't produce the required output (comparing to the authors' instructions in their journal website)

Comment: If they sent you a template I would just assume it is OK to use. Not all publishers that accept LaTeX submissions use LaTeX to publish their papers. Often they just convert your submission into a format that they use in their pipeline. It is very possible that during this conversion process the bibliography formatting is automatically fixed. If you are worried about the bibliography, ask the editor, if not, just use the template and see where it gets you on submission.

Comment: Thank you @moewe !!