# Bibliography issues with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sorting, bibliographystyle

I'm a latex beginner and am currently trying to configure my bibliography.
There are several issues:

- It sorts nty but I have specified nyt
- The author-name-sorting is wrong: it should be family, given
- Additional authors are printed initials only
- For internet resources the access date is not shown

Attached is a picture of how my current bibliography presents:
[image: Current bibliography]

I appreciate any ideas as I have run out.

Here's a mwe:

```
%% TEST BIBLATEX STYLE

\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    %style 
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}     %language
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


%%BIBLIOGRAPHY with BibLaTex & Citavi 
\usepackage[    autocite=superscript,
    hyperref=true,  
    %backref=true,  
    backend=bibtex,
    natbib=true,      
    sortcites=true,   
    style=numeric,   
    sorting=nyt,   
    url=true,   
    isbn=true,       
    doi=true, 
    firstinits=true, %Make given names as initials
    citetracker=true,
    pagetracker=true,
    %maxcitenames=3,    
    %maxbibnames=99,    
    block=none]{biblatex}   
\addbibresource{All.bib}


\begin{document}  %Startet Doc - NICHT LÖSCHEN!  
\let\cite\autocite    %CITATION: Set cite = autocite
\let\citep\autocite 
\let\cites\autocites 
\mbox


\section{CoRobX~Mission}
ESA's exploration programs sponsors projects to explore the Lunar environment with one focus on future Human habitation. 
These lava tubes are of special interest as shelter for long-term Human settlements, a concept that has gained traction in the recent renewed efforts of putting Humans on the Moon\cites{ESA.Scouting, Tombrowski.2018, Ximenes.2012}. 
%
As part of ESA's SysNova\cite{SysNova} initiative, the Skylight \cites{Skylight.2020, Skylight.2021} concept study in 2020 laid the foundation for the CoRob-X autonomous robotic exploration of Lunar lava tubes through skylights\cites{Corobx.2021, ESA.plans}. 
It explores the solutions to access and exploration of a Lunar skylight with micro-rovers on a tether system. 
The lowered rover is attached to a docking and recharging station, which holds the attachment to the tether system. The rover undocks and explores the cave, returns and then sends its data via the docking station\cite{Skylight.2020}. 
%
\\Under the CoRob-X mission the existing systems SherpaTT and Coyote III will be enhanced and matured for this mission. 
These Robotic Exploratio Units (REUs) will eventually be tasked with the underground exploration of Lunar skylights\citep{Corobx.2021}. 



%%BIBLIOGRAPHY
\newpage
\renewcommand*{\bibfont}{\scriptsize} 
\printbibliography[title={Quellen}]

\end{document}
```

And here's the respective .bib file:

```
@misc{Corobx.2021,
 author = {CoRob-X},
 year = {26/10/2021},
 title = {COROB-X: Cooperative Robots for Extreme Environments},
 url = {https://www.corob-x.eu/},
 urldate = {26/10/2021}
}


@misc{Coyote.2021,
 author = {{DFKI GmbH}},
 year = {2021},
 title = {Robotersystem: Coyote III},
 url = {https://robotik.dfki-bremen.de/de/forschung/robotersysteme/coyote-iii/},
 address = {Bremen},
 urldate = {18/12/2021}
}


@misc{ESA.plans,
 abstract = {In a first step towards uncovering the Moon's subterranean secrets, in 2019 we asked for your ideas to detect, map and explore lunar caves. Five ideas were selected to be studied in more detail, each addressing different phases of a potential mission.},
 author = {ESA},
 year = {2021},
 title = {ESA plans mission to explore lunar caves},
 url = {https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Preparing_for_the_Future/Discovery_and_Preparation/ESA_plans_mission_to_explore_lunar_caves},
 urldate = {18/12/2021}
}


@misc{ESA.Scouting,
 author = {ESA},
 year = {2021},
 title = {Scouting and mapping lava tubes from the Moon's surface: Lunar Lava Tube Scouting Mission},
 url = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLefVG7QObk&t=1365s},
 urldate = {18/12/2021},
 isbn = {https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLefVG7QObk{\&}t=1365s},
 editor = {YouTube}
}

@misc{Skylight.2021,
 author = {ESA},
 year = {2021},
 title = {Skylight: A tethered micro-rover for safe semi-autonomous exploration of lava tubes},
 url = {https://www.esa.int/ESA_Multimedia/Videos/2021/02/Skylight_A_tethered_micro-rover_for_safe_semi-autonomous_exploration_of_lava_tubes},
 urldate = {18/12/2021}
}

@misc{SysNova,
 author = {ESA},
 title = {SysNova: What is SysNova?},
 url = {https://www.esa.int/Enabling_Support/Preparing_for_the_Future/Discovery_and_Preparation/SysNova2},
 urldate = {18/12/2021}
}


@article{Tombrowski.2018,
 author = {Tombrowski, Lucas,Mardon, Austin},
 year = {2018},
 title = {Lunar lava tubes: a potential option for future human habitation on the lunar surface},
 pages = {B3.1-68-18},
 volume = {42},
 journal = {42nd COSPAR Scientific Assembly},
 file = {https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2018cosp...42e3404t/abstract}
}

@inproceedings{Ximenes.2012,
 author = {Ximenes, Samuel W.,Elliott, J. O.,Bannova, O.},
 title = {Defining a Mission Architecture and Technologies for Lunar Lava Tube Reconnaissance},
 pages = {344--354},
 publisher = {{American Society of Civil Engineers}},
 isbn = {9780784412190},
 editor = {Zacny, Kris,Malla, Ramesh B.,Binienda, Wieslaw},
 booktitle = {Earth and Space 2012},
 year = {04172012},
 address = {Reston, VA},
 doi = {10.1061/9780784412190.038},
 file = {http://ascelibrary.org/doi/book/10.1061/9780784412190}
}
```

Comment: Some comments: 1) The name seperator is 'and' meaning if you have two authors, you can write it like this: 'F. Lastname1 and K. Lastname2'. It doesn't matter if you write 'Firstname Lastname  and ' because biblatex will fix this. 2) You do not have Skylight.2020 in the bib file. 3) Year in Ximenes.2012 is 04172012 4) firstinits should be giveninits. 5) you have not loaded hyperref package and the `hyperref=true` option will not work 6) Url format is `urldate = {2016-07-26}` or `YYYY-MM-DD`.

Comment: Please only ask about one issue per question. That makes it easier to answer your questions precisely and to the point and that makes questions and answers more relevant for other people as well. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7425/35864.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the anser to your points:

- It actually sorts by nyt not nty. Notice that ESA sys nova does not have a year and thus is first. Then comes all the others, which has the same year: 2021. They are then sorted by title because they all have the same year. nyt does ***not*** sort by urldate.
- See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290103/get-last-name-first-in-biblatex-using-numeric-style). Short version: use `\DeclareNameAlias{author}{last-first}` in the preamble.
- This is because you have seperated the authors wrong. You must use "and" to seperate multiple authors: `John Doe and Jane Doe`. It does not matter that you provide the authors in the format `GivenName FamilyName` because LaTeX will correct this.
- The date is not shown because you have provided it in the wrong format. The date format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. Note that the numbers is seperated by `-` and not `/`.

---

Some other remarks:

1. You must use `giveninits` instead of `firstinits`.
2. ISBN of ESA.Scouting is an url.
3. Ximenes.2012 year is set to 04172012
4. Year of Corobx.2021 is a date and invalid. You can change the field to `date=` or `year=2021`.
5. I would suggest changing `backend=bibtex` to `backend=biber` and get rid of `natbib=true` (I use biblatex and have not used this option).